# How to style a Django editable form in bootstrap

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I have a form that returns the following fields:

```
fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

So in my `profile/edit` view(I mean an HTML page) I have this code:

```
<div class="col-xl-9">
        <div class="widget has-shadow" style="height:100%">
            <div class="widget-header bordered no-actions d-flex align-items-center">
                <h4>edit profile</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group row d-flex align-items-center mb-5">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 form-control-label d-flex justify-content-lg-end">username</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="{{update_profile_form.username}}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="em-separator separator-dashed"></div>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-gradient-01" type="submit">Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-shadow" type="reset">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And you see I want to show `username` field from `update_profile_form` form. But when I reload the page I have an extra `">` below of my username field.

I don't know how to get rid of these characters in my page.

## Update

my `forms.py` looks like:

```
class AccountUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']

    def clean_username(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            try:
                account = Account.objects.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk).get(username=username)
            except Account.DoesNotExist:
                return username
            raise forms.ValidationError('The username "%s" is now allowed to be used!', username)
```

and my `views.py` is:

```
def edit_profile_view(request):
    context = {}
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')

    if request.POST:
        upd_form = AccountUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if upd_form.is_valid():
            upd_form.save()
    else: # Get request
        upd_form = AccountUpdateForm(
            initial = {
                "username": request.user.username,
            }
        )
    context = {'update_profile_form': upd_form}
    return render(request, 'account/user/edit-profile.html', context)
```

Comment: i think `update_profile_form.username` is an input field.

Comment: I updated the question. Would you please take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of initials I need to do:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="{{update_profile_form.initial.username}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace this line

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="{{update_profile_form.username}}">
```

with

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="{{request.user.username}}">
```

you do not have to provide initial values to your form in your views.

Comment: It works. But why can't we use form here?

Comment: `initial` sets values to the fields of the form... not the placeholder.
so instead of
`<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="{{update_profile_form.username}}">`
if you write
`{{update_profile_form.username}}` you will have a field with the value of username on the page load